# Angular and KeyCloack - Redirect to route when role is not authorized to acess

Tags: angular, keycloak

I'm trying to redirect to an unauthorized route when a role tries to access an unauthorized route,
I'm using keycloack-angular lib:

> npm install keycloak-angular keycloak-js

**My Guard**

```
export class AuthGuard extends KeycloakAuthGuard {
  constructor(
    protected readonly router: Router,
    protected readonly keycloak: KeycloakService
  ) {
    super(router, keycloak);
  }

  public async isAccessAllowed(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    if (!this.authenticated) {
      await this.keycloak.login({
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + state.url,
      });
    }
    const requiredRoles = route.data.roles;
    if (!(requiredRoles instanceof Array) || requiredRoles.length === 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      if (!this.roles || this.roles.length === 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return requiredRoles.every((role) => this.roles.includes(role));

  }
}
```

**Routing:**

```
   const routes: Routes = [
...    
      {
        path: 'testar',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./core/modules/testar/testar.module').then((m) => m.TestarModule),
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: { roles: ['admin', 'user'] }
      },
    
      { path: 'notauthorized', component: NotauthorizedComponent },
    
    ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't used the router instance to redirect to another route when access is not allowed. Call the navigate statement to redirect wherever you return `false`:

```
if (!requiredRoles.every((role) => this.roles.includes(role))) {
  this.router.navigate(['/']);
}
```